# Ограничение количества колонок в JTable

Tags: java, swing

Реализуя один проект, принял решение выводить информацию в JTable. Из-за специфики данных (64 массива в которых от 380 до 1000 Float значений) было принято решение разместить массивы не в колонках, а в строках, таким образом получилась таблица 64 строки на 380 (1000) столбцов.

И вот столкнулся с проблемой: на 380 колонках все работает отлично, но уже на ~450 значениях возникают исключения, непонятные мне. Для JTable в качестве модели использую класс, расширяющий AbstractTableModel.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Хм.. а можно больше деталей? Какого рода исключения возникают? Можно пример такого исключения? Неверное использование? Синхронизация?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема возникала из-за ошибки в моей модели таблицы. Исправив эту ошибку JTable с легкостью отображает тысячи колонок. И, как я понимаю, количество колонок ограничено только доступной памятью.

Comment: Я так и думал ;)